# Knowing if UIView was pushed from the More menu of a UITabBar

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbar

Is there a method to know when a UIView was pushed by the user from the More view of a UITabbar ?

I have multiple views in a UITabBar and some end up in the More view where they are listed. Il'd like to be able to know when the view is pushed from this More view as opposed to when it is pushed from a UITabBarItem

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check if the controller's navigation controller is the more navigation controller:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (self.navigationController == self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController) {
        NSLog(@"Launcehed from more");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Launcehed from tab bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question says `UITabBar` but I suspect you mean `UITabBarController`. Based on how some options "end up in the More view", which is provided automatically by `UITabBarController`.

If you do mean `UITabBarController` then yes a `UIViewController` presented by a `UITabBarController` can very easily determine whether it is in the more options or not.

```
[self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self];
```

This will return a `BOOL` that is true if the option for that view controller (`self`) is listed in the `More` section of the `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 0):

No, `UITabbarController` doesn't expose that information.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass the UIView and add a property `sentFrom` which you would pass along to the UIView when adding it in whatever controller. There is not an already implemented method that does it, so you have to keep track of such things by yourself.